# FluentD Save Cloud Foundry SYSLOG to a file on Client

Tags: cloud-foundry, fluentd, syslog

I have FluentD (td-agent) running on Windows machine.
A service on Cloud Found is running to ship logs to the machine.

`td-agen.conf` files looks like this.
I am able to get the logs to console.

```
<source>
  @type syslog
  port 8080
  bind 0.0.0.0
  tag cf.app
  message_length_limit 99990
  # frame_type octet_count
  <transport tcp>
  </transport>
</source>

<match cf.app>
  @type stdout
</match>

<match cf.app>
  @type file
  append true
  path C:\temp\fluentd\
</match>
```

> **Help Needed: Save the logs to `C:\temp\fluentd\`.
> I added another match directive but currently as-is configured, the logs are not saved to a file.**